# Changing brightness and contrast of portion of an image

Tags: c++, opencv

Given an image, I'd like to change the brightness/contrast on portion of an image.

I'm using an example [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc1/tutorial_basic_linear_transform.html) to change the brightness/contrast of the whole image:

```
RNG rng(cv::getTickCount());
float min_alpha = 0.1;
float max_alpha = 2.0;
float alpha = rng.uniform(min_alpha, max_alpha);
float beta = -2.0;
image.convertTo(new_image, -1, alpha, beta);
```

Is there a way to do this only on a subregion of an image without having to iterate through the entire image on a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in an easier/more efficient manner with the following steps:

Step 1: Crop the part in the image where you want to change the contrast.

Step 2: Apply suitable contrast/brightness changes to this cropped image.

Step 3: Paste the *changed image* back to the original image.

```
// Step 1
int rect_x = originalImg.cols / 5;
int rect_y = 0;
int rect_width = originalImg.cols / 6;
int rect_height = originalImg.rows;

cv::Rect ROI(rect_x, rect_y, rect_width, rect_height);
cv::Mat cropped_image = originalImg (ROI);

Mat image = imread( argv[1] );
Mat new_image = Mat::zeros( image.size(), image.type() );

// Step 2
std::cout<<" Basic Linear Transforms "<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"-------------------------"<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"* Enter the alpha value [1.0-3.0]: ";std::cin>>alpha;
std::cout<<"* Enter the beta value [0-100]: "; std::cin>>beta;

for( int y = 0; y < cropped_image.rows; y++ ) {
    for( int x = 0; x < cropped_image.cols; x++ ) {
        for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ ) {
            enhanced_cropped_image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[c] =
            saturate_cast<uchar>( alpha*( cropped_image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[c] ) + beta );
        }
    }
}
// Or this for Step 2
float min_alpha = 0.1;
float max_alpha = 2.0;
float alpha = rng.uniform(min_alpha, max_alpha);
float beta = -2.0;
cropped_image.convertTo(enhanced_cropped_image, -1, alpha, beta);
// Step 3
enhanced_cropped_image.copyTo(originalImg(cv::Rect(rect_x, rect_y, rect_width, rect_height)));
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it.

1. Change the brightness/contrast on the entire image
2. Specify a region with cv::Rect where you want to crop
3. Copy the cropped part to the same location in the original image

Here's a snippet I wrote:

```
 Mat partial_illum_img;
 RNG rng(cv::getTickCount());
 float min_alpha = 0.1;
 float max_alpha = 2.0;
 float alpha = rng.uniform(min_alpha, max_alpha);
 float beta = -2.0;
 image.convertTo(illum_img, -1, alpha, beta);
 image.copyTo(partial_illum_img);

 // Crop a rectangle from converted image
 int rect_x = illum_img.cols / 5;
 int rect_y = 0;
 int rect_width = illum_img.cols / 6;
 int rect_height = illum_img.rows;

 cv::Rect illumROI(rect_x, rect_y, rect_width, rect_height);
 cv::Mat crop_after_illum = illum_img(illumROI);
 crop_after_illum.copyTo(partial_illum_img(cv::Rect(rect_x, rect_y, rect_width, rect_height)));
```

Comment: You can do the same for a part of the image, I don't think there is a need to change the brightness/contrast of the entire image when you want to it for only a part

Comment: @RickM. Do you mean I can just specify Rect on the image and change its contrast?

Comment: Yes. You can extract the Rect from the image where you want to change contrast, do that and paste it back into the original image.

Comment: @RickM. Ah I see. If you write it as an answer, I can accept yours once I test it out

Comment: I can write it really fast in python. I can follow the link you posted and write it in C++ but you have to test it

Comment: @RickM. Gotcha. I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: Added the answer. See if it works well and let me know :)